# Как записать все данные из ссылок?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Пожалуйста, помогите найти решение, мне нужно скачать все файлы стилей со страницы в один файл. Для этого я использую `bs4` для получения всех ссылок. Для получения контента со страницы я использую `requests`

```
# Получаю строки с атрибутом stylesheet
all_url_links = soup.find_all(attrs={"rel": "stylesheet"})

for item in all_url_links:
    # Получаю все ссылки из атрибута href
    all_url_styles = item.get('href')

    # Отпраляю запрос на каждую страницу по ссылке
    page_style = requests.get(all_url_styles, headers=headers)
    
    # Записываю в файл
    with open('all_styles.css', 'w') as file:
        for i in page_style:
            file.write(page_style.text)
```

Но в файл записываются стили только из одной ссылки. Как мне записать все стили из всех ссылок которые я получил в переменной `all_url_styles`

Comment: Кст, странный код с `for i in page_style: file.write(page_style.text)`... Не думал, что `requests.Response` умеет итерироваться... UPD. реально умеет, перебирая кусками `content`

Comment: Но тогда у вас файл может быть раздут повторяющимся кусками стилей, вам не нужен `for i in page_style:`, достаточно `file.write(page_style.text)`

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил пример с `w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в `with open('all_styles.css', 'w') as file:`, а точнее в `w`. Этот флаг очищает файл перед тем как записать в него

Решением может быть использование флага `a`:

```
with open('all_styles.css', 'a') as file:
    file.write(page_style.text)
```

---

Еще вариантом будет заранее открыть файл и при переборе ссылок записывать в него:

```
# Получаю строки с атрибутом stylesheet
all_url_links = soup.find_all(attrs={"rel": "stylesheet"})

# Записываю в файл
with open('all_styles.css', 'w') as file:
    for item in all_url_links:
        # Получаю все ссылки из атрибута href
        all_url_styles = item.get('href')
    
        # Отпраляю запрос на каждую страницу по ссылке
        rs = requests.get(all_url_styles, headers=headers)
        file.write(rs.text + "\n")
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!